# How to get MySQL Workbench 6 to autocomplete columns?

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, workbench

Recently upgraded to MySQL workbench 6. However it only auto completes table names and SQL commands. Is there an option/add-on to complete column names?

Otherwise are there any other good linux GUI options that do have autocompletion with column names?

Answer (score 1):

I use ctrl+space for autocomplete in MySQL workbench for columns list

Comment: I tried this on MySQL Wb 8.0 and nothing. Can you add any other details about any additional set up you've made to the program?